# Strange behaviour of eigensystem

Tags: eigenvalues

I encounter with really strange behavior in calculating the eigensystem of a hermitian matrix.
I upload the [matrix here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xplXKT-8l1eGdoiBvL0BE-gUoMdkPitb/view?usp=sharing) After loading it you can construct the main matrix as follows

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
evv = Get["H.m"];
index=164
H = Normal@SparseArray[#[[1]] -> Exp[I index #[[2]]] & /@ evv, {1393,1393}] // # + #\[ConjugateTranspose] &;
```

Calculating eigenvalue and eigensystems takes just one second,

```
Eigenvalues[H]; // AbsoluteTiming
Eigensystem[H]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

However by putting

```
index=165
```

and reconstructing H and calculating eigenvalues and eigensystem, I realize eigenvalue just takes the same time as index=164, while eigensystem take lots of time, without any results. I try to add a very small number to the index, where I get the answer for 165, but for another index, I encounter the same problem.

Comment: 1. Please don't add [tag:bugs] tag to the question before it's confirmed. 2. Can't reproduce the mentioned behavior in _v12.1.1_, Win 10, which version and OS are you in?

Comment: I run it on Mathematica 12 in Linux and windows 10. Have you  find eigensystem? I would be thanks anyone find my problem comments here.

Comment: Yes, `0.470589` for `Eigenvalues[H]; // AbsoluteTiming` and `0.833236` for `Eigensystem[H]; // AbsoluteTiming` on my 2 GHz laptop. Just tested on _v12.0.1_, still cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @xzczd, please look at https://youtu.be/JU6-rI5t8-I

Comment: Hmm… strange. Have you contacted WRI support?

Comment: It seems this problem is machine-dependent. I try it in another system with mac and it works. Also adding a very small imaginary number to the index=165+i10^-20 solve the problem.

Comment: I just recalled this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221767/1871 Are you using a AMD CPU?

Comment: @xzczd no, I am using intel CPU in both workstation and desktop pc.