# How can I ingest and analyze benchmark results posted at MSE?

Tags: parsing, benchmarking

How can I ingest Mathematica / WL benchmark results posted at Mathematica Stack Exchange (MSE), like the ones posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234881/benchmarking-with-mathematica-v-12-for-up-to-date-comparison-across-different-ma)?

Assumptions:

- There are multiple answers with benchmarks posted
- The benchmark results have a certain clear "list of rules" form

See:

```
Needs["Benchmarking`"]
Benchmark[]

(* {"MachineName" -> "macbook-pro", "System" -> "Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)", "BenchmarkName" -> "WolframMark", "FullVersionNumber" -> "12.1.1", "Date" -> "November 26, 2020",
 "BenchmarkResult" -> 3.028, "TotalTime" -> 4.571, "Results" -> {{"Data Fitting", 0.291}, {"Digits of Pi", 0.249}, {"Discrete Fourier Transform", 0.363}, {"Eigenvalues of a Matrix", 0.297},
   {"Elementary Functions", 0.375}, {"Gamma Function", 0.356}, {"Large Integer Multiplication", 0.323}, {"Matrix Arithmetic", 0.227}, {"Matrix Multiplication", 0.218}, {"Matrix Transpose", 0.404},
   {"Numerical Integration", 0.463}, {"Polynomial Expansion", 0.068}, {"Random Number Sort", 0.449}, {"Singular Value Decomposition", 0.221}, {"Solving a Linear System", 0.267}}} *)
```

Comment: Please, if you upvoted (or inclined to do so) this question then (consider and) post benchmarks in the linked [MSE discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/234881). And if you do post your benchmark results, please post WL code output from `Benchmark[]` not just screenshots.

Comment: What is *"WL"*? In some Mathematica format, file extension .wl? Or simply Mathematica code? Wolfram Language Packages?

Comment: @PeterMortensen **1.** "What is "WL"?" -- WL stands for "Wolfram Language". I used "Mathematica" and "WL" as synonyms. **2.** "Or simply Mathematica code?" -- Yes, simply Mathematica code. (The output code from `Benchmark[]`.)

Comment: I challenge whoever downvoted to explain the reasons for the downvote. :)

Comment: Related community post: ["Ingest and analyze benchmark results posted at MathematicaStackExchange"](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2398046). (You can get the notebook from there.)

Answer (score 16):

### Ingestion

Get all answers from MSE discussion in an XML object:

```
xmlObject = 
  Import["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234881/benchmarking-with-mathematica-v-12-for-up-to-date-comparision-of-mathematica-acr/235384#235384", "XMLObject"];
```

Get code XML elements:

```
lsRes1 = Cases[xmlObject, XMLElement["code", {}, code_] :> code, \[Infinity]];
```

(Note of that at this point code strings are obtained.)

Remove `Benchmark` computation commands and convert the code strings into WL code:

```
lsRes2 = Map[(ToExpression[Map[If[StringQ[#] && SyntaxQ[#], #, Nothing] &, #]] &) @
    StringReplace[#, {"LaunchKernels[]" -> "", "BenchmarkReport[]" -> "", "Benchmark[]" -> ""}] &, lsRes1]
```

Select code (blocks) that are lists of rules:

```
lsRes3 = Select[Flatten /@ lsRes2, MatchQ[#, {_Rule ..}] && Length[#] > 1 &];
Length[lsRes3]

(*31*)
```

For each code block flatten the metadata and benchmark results into associations:

```
lsRes4 = Map[Association@ Cases[Flatten[# /.  HoldPattern["Results" -> r_] :> (Rule @@@ r)], _Rule] &, lsRes3];
Length[lsRes4]

(*31*)
```

Make sure all associations have the same keys:

```
lsRes5 = 
 Block[{lsAllKeys = Union[Flatten[Keys /@ lsRes4]]}, 
  Map[Join[AssociationThread[lsAllKeys, "NA"], #] &, lsRes4]
 ];
Length[lsRes5]

(*31*)
```

(Otherwise, the obtained dataset might be hard to use in some computations.)

Make a comparison dataset:

```
dsBenchmarks = Dataset[lsRes5];
dsBenchmarks = dsBenchmarks[SortBy[#BenchmarkResult &]]
```

[image]

### Basic analysis

Summarize the dataset:

```
ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][dsBenchmarks]
```

[image]

(Bar) plot results:

```
Multicolumn@
 KeyValueMap[
  If[VectorQ[DeleteCases[#2, _Missing | "NA"], NumericQ], 
    BarChart[#2, PlotLabel -> #1, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], 
    Nothing
  ] &, 
  Normal@Transpose@dsBenchmarks
]
```

[image]

### Breakdown statistics

Partition benchmark results per system (or other criteria):

```
aRes = GroupBy[Normal@dsBenchmarks, #System &, Dataset];
aRes = Map[#[All, Select[#, NumericQ] &] &, aRes];
```

Separate the overall benchmark results from the benchmark component results:

```
aRes2 = Map[#[All, KeyTake[#, {"BenchmarkResult", "TotalTime"}] &] &, aRes];
aRes3 = Map[#[All, KeyDrop[#, {"BenchmarkResult", "TotalTime"}] &] &, aRes];
```

Show the overall benchmark results:

```
aRes2
```

[image]

Show distribution statistical plots per system:

```
aResPlots3 = 
  BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[Normal[#[Values]]], 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"Number of benchmarks:", Spacer[2], Length[#]}], 
     ChartStyle -> 56, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
     ChartLegends -> Keys[Normal@#[[1]]]] & /@ aRes3;
Grid[List @@@ Normal[aResPlots3], Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7]]
```

[image]

(Note, that we have to keep an eye on the number of available benchmarks per system. Those numbers are too small here...)

#### Older plots

[image]

Comment: I’ve also come to find that the benchmark rarely uses 100% of my systems cpu to do calculations...i’ll get spikes up to 65% and a score that varies +- 0.3

Comment: @morbo Hmm... interesting observation. I guess you can post question(s) at MSE about modifying the “standard” benchmark in a way that makes it more computationally challenging and/or how to get/include the CPU utilization. (Of course, certain algorithms just cannot be executed that effectively on certain CPU-OS configurations.)