# Generating Gaussian-distributed initial conditions from a given bivariate probability density function

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have a coupled system of ODE's for which I would like to choose some initial conditions in the variables `(x1,x2)` at some initial time, `t = -2` (the form of the ODE's doesn't really matter here). I'd like to choose the set of initial conditions so that they match the weighting of the density plot according to the function below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]


p1 = 1/\[Pi] 4 \[Sigma]^2 (E^(-2 (2 t^2 + 2 t x1 + x1^2 - 2 t x2 + 
        x2^2) \[Sigma]^2) k0 + 
    E^(-2 (2 t^2 - 2 t x1 + x1^2 + 2 t x2 + x2^2) \[Sigma]^2) k0 + 
    2 E^(-2 (2 t^2 + x1^2 + x2^2) \[Sigma]^2)
      k0 Cos[k0 (x1 - x2)]^2 - 
    2 E^(-2 (2 t^2 + x1^2 + x2^2) \[Sigma]^2) k0 Sin[k0 (x1 - x2)]^2)

k0 = 15;
\[Sigma] = 1;
t = -2;

DensityPlot[p1, {x1, -3, 3}, {x2, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

producing the following plot

[image]

For example, I'd like to have the initial conditions such that a lot of initial points are centred around `(x1,x2) = (-2,2)` and `(x1,x2) = (2,-2)` respectively, with the concentration of points decreasing as one moves away from the centre of the two Gaussians. I tried extracting the points which form evenly spaced contours of the density plot above, but it didn't yield the kind of weighted spacing between the initial conditions that I'd hoped for.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at "RandomVariate" in the help.

Comment: First, you need to define a distribution for the initial condition. In your case either as a [`MixtureDistribution`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267655/764) of bivariate `NormalDistribution` or you can use the density function`p1[x1,x2]` within [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html?q=ProbabilityDistribution). Secondly, you can sample from that bivariate distribution using `RandomVariate` as suggested by Daniel.