# Tutorial example NetTrain fails miserably with a GPU

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu, amazon-web-services

I have been experimenting with GPU `NetTrain` on AWS now when Mma 12.2 supports remote batch jobs (I don't have an Nvidia GPU to try these things out otherwise). In particular, I'm puzzled by the example on Mathematica documentation tutorial: [Sequence Learning and NLP with Neural Networks, Language Modeling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksSequenceLearning.html#1013067167), `teacherForcingNet` variant. After evaluating requisites, this example does training like this:

```
result = NetTrain[teacherForcingNet, <|"Input" -> Keys[trainingData]|>,
   All, BatchSize -> 64, MaxTrainingRounds -> 5, 
  TargetDevice -> "CPU", ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1]]
```

A CPU-based run, also if run on AWS, results a network with around 40% loss.

I have minimally modified the `NetTrain` step to perform this on GPU, and to run it on AWS:

```
job = RemoteBatchSubmit[env, 
  NetTrain[teacherForcingNet, <|"Input" -> Keys[trainingData]|>, All, 
   BatchSize -> 64, MaxTrainingRounds -> 5, TargetDevice -> "GPU", 
   ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1]], 
  TimeConstraint -> Quantity[30, "Minutes"], 
  RemoteProviderSettings -> <|"GPUCount" -> 1|>]
```

When the training job completes, the resulting training object is available as `job["EvaluationResult"]` (and progress can be actually observed on runtime through `job["JobLog"]`). The problem is that when CPU-based training results error rate of around 41%, GPU-based run gets stuck at about 82% (effectively without learning anything).

What gives? Is this common behaviour for some networks (LeNet on MNIST dataset works just fine on GPU, for instance), a bug that needs fixing, and/or is a workaround available? Neither `Method` nor `WorkingPrecision` changes give difference in results.

Comment: Executing the first example at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksSequenceLearning.html#1013067167 with `Round@trained[{"5+2", "10+25", "9+11", "44+44"}]`, I obtain `{8,35,18,88}`.

Comment: @user64494 That example is on the sequence regression section, I'm referring to language modelling section. I should probably try other examples with AWS cloud GPUs too, but my current interest happens to lie in language modelling...

Comment: @kima: Here is an example  in the field you are interested in. Also `generate[net_, start_, len_] := 
 StringJoin@NestList[NetStateObject[net], start, len]` `generateSample[trainedNet, "Why are w", 100]` does not work for me.

Comment: @user64494 The tutorial example works fine for me, there's no problem when training is done with CPU. The specific issue I'm facing is that corresponding training on a GPU doesn't result useful networks...

Comment: I am working with 12.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: There is a typo in the documentation: `generate[net_, start_, len_] :=   StringJoin@NestList[NetStateObject[net], start, len] ` `generate[trainedNet, "Why are w", 100]` indeed works, but not `generateSample[trainedNet, "Why are w", 100]`.

Comment: Strangely I get exactly the same result on my local machine - on GPU, the error rate doesn't descend at all.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't come up with any reason for this behaviour at all. I've tried everything I can think of to get some different result out of the GPU-trained version with no luck - though GPU training generally works fine. I would guess there's some bug in the GPU library triggered by this network - I'd say file a bug.

Comment: I am getting good (~40%) error rate on GPU (Wolfram Language 12.2 + Linux + GTX 1650). Can you provide details of your systems (OS + GPU model)? Also for @CarlLange

Comment: Same as you, 12.2, Pop!_OS, GTX 1650 (GDDR6 variant). Other details are here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234881/benchmarking-with-mathematica-v-12-for-up-to-date-comparison-across-different-ma/238024#238024

Comment: Intriguing if this is dependent on hardware/OS configuration in some way...

Comment: Could this relate to either 1) version of the MXNetResources paclet or 2) version of local CUDA runtime, drivers, etc.?

Comment: @JesseFriedman I understand this can be broken on some installation environments - maybe there's room to be more specific on their requirements. The fact that it's broken on the WRI-supplied AWS batch environment image is, though, something that should just work - or am I mistaken?