# May the runtime of a code compiled in C depend on the C compiler used?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, windows, ccompilerdriver

I have a Windows machine with installed Mathematica. I compile the code in C. The compiler I use is `` CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler `` from Visual Studio Express. Does anyone know whether there may be a difference between the runtime of the code depending on the compiler?

The reason I am asking is that the same code on Mac is evaluated ~3 times faster. This may be due to the difference in OS and CPU, but who knows.

The code deals with some table, computes the values of some functions using the elements of the table (multiplication, etc.), and makes other similar actions.

Comment: Such a large difference is due to hardware differences, not the compiler, and definitely not the OS. Apple's arm-based processors are very fast.

Comment: @Szabolcs : indeed, there definitely may be such a component. However, what is interesting is whether there may be some differences in Windows due to different compilers.

Comment: Only a few percent, not a 3x difference. You can look up various compiler benchmarks to get an idea.

Comment: @Szabolcs : I have the benchmark result ~3.3 in this test: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234881/benchmarking-with-mathematica-v-12-for-up-to-date-comparison-across-different-ma?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top 

Overall, competitive with MacBooks. I am not sure that this number represents the performance of running the compiled code though.

Comment: @Szabolcs : the friend has M1 Pro with 8+2 cores, and 32 Gb of RAM.

Comment: It depends quite heavily on the tasks. For example some compilers are better at vectorizing code as others. And things like this apply to many other compiler optimizations as well. But as Szabolcs said, a 3x difference only due to the compiler would be really, really unexpected. If that happened on the same hardware, then I'd would rather check whether all optimizations flags were correctly set and whether debugging mode is turned off. In different hardware I'd  tend to blame it on the hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately, the _WolframMark_ is not really representative. It was developped for much older CPUs and I think it is not suited for differentiating between recent processor (e.g., because many of the tests are so "tiny" that one has a substantial portion of overhead in the measrued runtimes).

Comment: Moreover, it could be that the Windows machine seems to perform better in these benchmarks because _Mathematica_ on Windows uses the Intel MKL which is heavily optimized for Intel machine. On the mac side, parts of this are covered by Apple's _Accelerate_ framework, but not all of them. And I am not sure to which extent _Mathematica_ on a mac makes use of _Accelerate_. So the M1 might not shine as bright as it could in these benchmarks.