# Can Mathematica be made to use AMD's Optimizing CPU Libraries?

Tags: mkl

I have a AMD Ryzen Threadripper CPU. I am wondering whether it is possible for Mathematica to use AMD's Optimizing CPU Libraries (AOCL) instead of MKL. Is there an easy way to make this happen.

An earlier question had offered a workaround with the MKL.
[Earlier Stack Exchange Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221767/does-the-following-change-to-mkl-environment-variable-boost-mathematica-speed-on)

This no longer works.

Comment: MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5 still works. You just need to apply it using special program. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49113

Comment: This patching procedure does not work. Also, I reached out to Wolfram Research and they said that as of now Mathematica cannot use AOCL. It may be possible in future versions.